# Existence and uniqueness of $y$ such that $xy=(xy)^2$ for every real $x$

Tags: real-numbers

I've been asked to prove this theorem: *There exists a unique $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have*
$$xy = (xy)^2$$

Now, this may seem rather silly, but I'm wondering if this theorem is even true. Clearly, if $y = 1/x$, then regardless of what $x$ is, we would get 1 = 1 on the left hand side and right hand side.
However, the theorem also holds if $y = 0$. Since we have two values for which the theorem holds, namely, $y = 0$ and $y = 1/x$, does this mean that the existence is not unique?

Comment: What is $R$????

Comment: $y$ has to be the same for all $x$, that is, it must be independent of $x$. This is not the case for $y=1/x$.

Comment: Yes, I got the answer now. y = 1/x does not hold when x = 0, and so it does not hold $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. So xy = 0 is what I'm looking for. Thanks. Please mark as resolved.

Comment: Y=1/x is invalid! Y cannot be a function of x.

Answer (score 2):

There is in fact a unique value that holds for every $x$ and that value is $0$. You cannot choose $x$ first and you cannot have $y$ depend on $x$. The order of the quantifiers is very important in this statement .